# Calculate total variation $V_0^{2\pi}(f) $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations

I am reviewing an analysis book and this exercise comes, in another example using the piecewise function many steps are skipped.
Will you help me understand how to make my partitions with this example please.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ for }x=0 \\
x&\text{ for }x\in \left (  0,\pi \right ]\\
\sin x&\text{ for }x\in \left (  \pi,2\pi \right ]\end{cases}$$

Comment: It seems that you are mixing [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) for functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and for function s on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do you mean for each $y$ compute the variation of $x\mapsto f_y(x)$?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes, I am trying to use Total variation for functions of one real variable like in this example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3636981/840578.Could you explain me please? :c

Comment: I just don't understand the role of $y$. But if $y$ is fixed, notice that each of your functions is piecewise differentiable. so $\int^{2\pi}_0|f'_y(x)|\,dx$ will do. The derivative is with respect to $x$. When $y=0$ the variation is $0$ when $y\neq0$ then $\int^\pi_0,dx +\int^{2\pi}_\pi|\cos x|\,dx$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Sorry MY BAD :( is only in f(x).

Comment: Well then, just remove the $y$ from my last comment. The integral there is what you are looking for. Intuitively $|f(x_i)-f(x_{I-1})|\approx|f'(t_i)|\Delta_i$. that explains why the integral of the absolute value of the derivative gives you the answer you are looking form in this case. Let me know if tis is clear enough.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you very much you are an angel

Answer (score 0):

$$V_0^{2\pi} = 1+\int_0^{\pi} |(x)' |dx +\pi +\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} |(\sin x )' |dx$$

Comment: YEs, that is in my comment already. Just let the OP do some of the heavy lifting.